# Discrepancy between integrating over a continuous mass and intuition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

Looking at the first problem on the page, [Physics LAB: Advanced Gravitational Forces](http://dev.physicslab.org/Document.aspx?doctype=3&filename=UniversalGravitation_UniversalGravitationForces.xml), and I have a little confusion:

I totally follow and agree with the solution presented, but I'm wondering why I can't also do the problem this way...

Suppose we take the rod to be a point mass of $\lambda L$ at a distance $a+\frac{L}{2}$ to find a gravitational force of $$F=\frac{GM\lambda L}{(a+\frac{L}{2})^2}.$$

Clearly the two are not equivalent, so there's something wrong with my reasoning. But what is it? The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced by the math. It's my intuition that's lacking.

Edit:

Now I feel good about this particular example, but the discussion brings up another question. Why then can we treat a sphere as a point mass when we're outside of the sphere? What is particular is special about that geometry?

Comment: You could also make a barbell of length L to convince yourself your logic is wrong, with 2 equal point masses at the ends. The center of mass is still in the center of the barbell, but you can quickly check that the forces won't work out if you just put all the mass at the center. The closer mass counts for more.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could make the post self-contained so that one does not have to click the link to understand the question, and to prevent future linkrot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake in your reasoning is that the mass elements that are closer to you (on the closer side from the center) exert more gravitational force than those that are far away. So it is unjustified to treat the mass distribution as a mass sitting at the center.

Imagine for instance a linear mass of infinite length, then according to your intuition, the force should be $$\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty} \frac{GM\lambda L}{(a + L/2)^2} =0$$
which is obviously counterintuitive for an infinitely massive rod.

So to treat this problem consistently you should give more relevance to those mass elements who are closer to you, than those who are farther.

Consequently we can treat it as a point particle of mass $m=\lambda L$ located at $r=\sqrt{a(a+L)}$ which is much closer than your $a + L/2$